Env variables are not working in Vue 3 with Vite and Typescript
Variables of environment (env) just not working in the App Vue 3 with Vite and Typescript.
I tried a lot of advices and nothing works.

The problem was that file of env:
env.d.ts
didn't have the dot before its name.
So it should be:
.env.d.ts
But I deleted all this typescript stuff and just stayed:
.env
And this working!
Be cautios.
